# Wagtail: Page content on search results page?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

Is there some way to access the content of a Page on the search results page?

In this configuration, the title, url, and Search Description fields are available.

```
def search(request):
search_query = request.GET.get('q', None)

if search_query:
    search_results = Page.objects.live().search(search_query)

    # Log the query so Wagtail can suggest promoted results
    Query.get(search_query).add_hit()
else:
    search_results = Page.objects.none()

return render(request, 'website/templates/search_results.html', {
    'search_query': search_query,
    'search_results': search_results,
})
```

What can I add to access the other fields of a Page in `search_results`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `specific` to return the page in its most specific subclassed form.
https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.4/reference/pages/model_reference.html#wagtail.core.models.Page.specific

In your template:

```
{% for result in search_results %}
  {{ result.specific.some_field }}
{% endfor %}
```